# Get Chinese characters from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to display chinese characters that I have saved in MySQL database, which is saved under utf8_unicode_ci type. I have seen several solutions on the web, but nothing works.

Below is my connection file:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ");
mysql_select_db("database");
```

Below is my query:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $conn);

$sql = mysql_query("select * from webdata",$conn);
```

But it still shows ????. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is that you cannot display Chinese characters on your computer as interpret that language. You might need to add Chinese as an input language to do this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have this <meta charset="utf-8"> in your html?How do you display the data?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. But I am able to display the characters if I coded the characters directly to my HTML. But for some reason, when I try to pull it from MySQL, it doesn't show.

Comment: I do have the meta charset. I display it using $sql['chinese_data'];

Comment: So have you solved your question? And if so please post it so we could know what you have done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to resolve...

When I had a similar issue I firstly displayed the encoding of my text in php using

```
echo mb_detect_encoding ( $text );
```

It shows the encoding of the text coming from my query. This showed me that I was getting ASCII from mysql_query when Chinese or Russian characters were in my database.

The change I made was with the following addition after the mysql_connect

```
mysql_set_charset('UTF8');
```

My database is utf8_unicode_ci  collation and I can see chinese characters.

So, if mb_detect_encoding is now giving you UTF8 for your text then you would be able to show chinese characters.

The next step is to make sure what you pass to the browser has the correct header...

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Put the above at the top of your code in php to make sure the browser is expecting your encoding.

Now that should the question, however ideally you should be using PDO or mysqli rather than mysql_connect method. In this case the equivalent procedural style commands are..

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'test');
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

Where $link is the equivalent to your connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

where it show "???", when you print the output to HTML ?
if so, try to add to `<head>` element the line

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

hope it helped a bit.

**EDIT**
it seems that you need to declare UTF8 on:

1. character_set_results = 'utf8',
2. character_set_client = 'utf8',
3. character_set_connection = 'utf8',
4. character_set_database = 'utf8',
5. character_set_server = 'utf8'"

checkout 
[PHP UTF8 not displaying chinese characters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143452/php-utf8-not-displaying-chinese-characters-properly)

Comment: Yes when I output to HTML, I added the meta tag, but it is still the same.

Comment: is the data in the database is stored correctly in chinese ??

Comment: Yes, I checked the data in the database, and it shows the chinese characters

Comment: can you add your entire <head> to question?

Comment: I tested  <?php
    $value = "黄后乎";
    echo $value;
    ?> to echo a chinese character from PHP, and it works. Perhaps its the database connection problem then?

Comment: checkout the link in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143452/php-utf8-not-displaying-chinese-characters-properly

Comment: To confirm that you _stored_ it correctly, SELECT HEX(col) should give you `E9BB84E5908EE4B98E` for `黄后乎`.

Comment: You should consider using utf8mb4 instead of utf8, since there are a few 4-byte Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1):

That should be all you need. Both for Traditional and Simplified Chinese characters

```
 1. Make sure your table is set to COLLATION utf8_general_ci
 2. $con = new mysqli("localhost",$username,$password,$database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con)); $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 3. <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```